# Failed to find rosdep libglui-dev for package view_mesh on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,

I am new to ros. I am trying to compile bosch_surface_reconstruction package on my UBUNTU 11.10 system. I installed ros-electric on my system as mentioned on the wiki page.

I dowloaded complete bosch repository in one of my folders and I added that folder path to ros stack path. When I run "rosmake --rosdep-install" in bosch_surface_reconstruction directory I get following error :

**Failed to find rosdep libglui-dev for package view_mesh on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric**

Failed to find rosdep libdevil-dev for package view_mesh on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric

Failed to find rosdep libann for package view_mesh on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric

Failed to find rosdep libglew-dev for package view_mesh on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric

How can I fix this error?..I could not install these packages with rosedep --install command, as it gives error that it could not find these packages.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks
Avanindra

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12487/failed-to-find-rosdep-libglui-dev-for-package-view_mesh-on-os:ubuntu-version:oneiric/) by [avanindra](https://answers.ros.org/users/1592/avanindra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2012-06-10**:
Hi Avanindra, I am still working on the proper releases for various Ubuntu version. Will come back to you as soon as that is done. D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means that the rule which defines libglew-dev does not cover ubuntu:oneiric.  You need to find which stack's rosdep.yaml defines libglew-dev and add rules for ubuntu oneiric.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2